# Parse Php Get current user information

Tags: php, parse-platform

in javascript when I wanted to get any column of the current user I simply used:

```
Parse.User.current().get("anything");
```

In Php I don't know how to do it, and i could't find anything in the docs, can some one explain to me how to do it? thanks.

I was able to convert the Parse object to an array, but I still cant get the information because I don't know how to apply the syntax, When I print the array i get this:

> Array ( [*_sessionToken] => r:mRy6rpWrsIQe4Yf86YWlxu4nC [*serverData]
>   => Array ( [Tipo] => Burger [name] => Burger Lab [username] => burgerlab ) [*operationSet] => Array ( )
>   [Parse\ParseObjectestimatedData] => Array ( [type] => Burger [name] =>
>   Burger Lab [username] => burgerlab )
>   [Parse\ParseObjectdataAvailability] => Array ( [type] => 1 [name] => 1
>   [sessionToken] => 1 [username] => 1 ) [Parse\ParseObjectclassName] =>
>   _User [Parse\ParseObjectobjectId] => 6J6RDBXLoU [Parse\ParseObjectcreatedAt] => DateTime Object ( [date] => 2015-10-23
>   04:21:57.147000 [timezone_type] => 2 [timezone] => Z )
>   [Parse\ParseObjectupdatedAt] => DateTime Object ( [date] => 2015-10-23
>   04:22:10.390000 [timezone_type] => 2 [timezone] => Z )
>   [Parse\ParseObjecthasBeenFetched] => 1 )

I'm trying to get the "name" value, I tried using:

```
$array["name"]
```

But it doesn't work, how can I know the index?

Solved:
This is how I got the value:

```
$username=ParseUser::getCurrentUser()->get("name");
```

Comment: This question is very unclear, please add more details informing us what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: In my User class, I have the column, beside of the defaults ones, "name",  so I'm trying to get that information (of current user), as I mention in the post, with java is pretty simple, but I don't quit get it in php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved: This is how I got the value:

```
$username=ParseUser::getCurrentUser()->get("name");
```

Answer (score 0):

yes very unclear question, but i assume you you will be parsing a multidimensional array, if so, you can start here : http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Comment: Updated, I used your idea, but I don't know how to go on.